# laravel проблемы с "a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: laravel

Модель организована с 2я внешними ключами:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('workers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('organization_id')->constrained();
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

в шаблоне выводятся поля для пользователя и организации для последующего выбора

```
<label for="user_id" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Пользователь</label>
                <select id="user_id" name="user_id" autocomplete="country" class="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                  @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
```

обрабатывает это все одна функция

```
ublic function store() {
        $this->validate([
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'organization_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        Worker::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->worker_id], [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'organization_id' => $this->organization_id,
            'active' => $this->active
        ]);

        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }
```

в результате получаю ошибку типа

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bill`.`workers`,
> CONSTRAINT `workers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
> REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `workers` (`user_id`,
> `organization_id`, `active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 0,
> 1, 2020-12-19 18:18:43, 2020-12-19 18:18:43))

хотя значения полей user_id organization_id передаются корректно. Подставляются 0 и 0. Как это вылечить?

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate([
        'user_id'         => 'required',
        'organization_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    Worker::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->worker_id], [
        'user_id'         => $request->user_id,
        'organization_id' => $request->organization_id,
        'active'          => $request->active
    ]);

    $this->closeModal();
    $this->resetInputFields();
}
```

Comment: пример выше возвращает SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `workers` (`user_id`, `organization_id`, `active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, 2020-12-20 10:55:57, 2020-12-20 10:55:57))

Comment: В импортной литературе пишут, что из формы возвращается строка и нужно делать что-то типа assosiate() чтобы модель понимала какое значение ей подставлять...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снимается.
Ничего делать не надо. Как я понял, вся проблема была в правильном написании шаблона, а именно за место **name** нужно писать **wire:model**

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно у вас в миграции отсутствует nullable перед constrained. У вас вряд ли есть пользователь и организация с id 0.